# Change Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Expander Title property when expanded

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Can this be done with just Xaml in UWP? If so how?

source code: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/main/dev/Expander

run: `winui2gallery://item/Expander` for demo

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.expander?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IsEqualStateTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/triggers) in NuGet package [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Triggers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/) to handle Expander expansion events in XAML.

```
<!--xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:triggers="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Triggers"-->

<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:IsEqualStateTrigger Value="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=myExpander, Mode=OneWay}" To="true" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="myExpander.Header" Value="This is Expander.StateTriggers"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <controls:Expander x:Name="myExpander" Header="This is Expander.Header" Content="This is Expander.Content"/>
</Grid>
```